# How to disable oom-killer on created containers using docker service create?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

any ideas how to pass the `--oom-kill-disable` flag when creating containers using `docker service create`? This parameter is documented on [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) but I'm wondering if its possible to use it for docker service.

When added as parameter to `docker service create` I am getting this error:

```
unknown flag: --oom-kill-disable
```

Thanks!

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

It isn't supported by all v3 (swarm) stuff. You may check `cgroup` settings to set it manually and check if it works:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/<ContainerId>/memory.oom_control
oom_kill_disable 1
```

[How to find cgroup](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#control-groups)

[cgroup manpages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html)